# AngularJS function called itself in the form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

in my form I have some input which is my custom directive and some text field. Additionally I have buttons: first one is for "Add new input to form" which binds to function `$scope.AddNewItem()` in my controller, second one is for "Remove input from form" which binded to function `$scope.RemoveItem(index_of_item)`. Problem occurs when I type in my text field and press enter - input value is deleted because `$scope.RemoveItem(index_of_item)` is called itself. I'm sure I'm not call it because even Call Stack doesn't show the place where I could do it. 
Does anybody has the same problem?

```
<div class="form-group " ng-repeat="(i, user) in users">
    <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px">
        <div typeahead ng-model="users[i]"> </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2 ng-scope" style="padding-left: 5px; margin-top: 0px">
        <button ng-click="removeUserInput(i)" class="btn pull-right m-t-n-xs remove-input">
            <i>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="color: white;"></span>
                </i>
        </button>
        <button ng-click="addUserInput()" class="btn pull-right m-t-n-xs add-input">
            <i>
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: white;"></span>
                </i>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my controller code:

```
   $scope.addUserInput = function () {
        $scope.users.push({});
    };

    $scope.removeUserInput = function (index) {
        if ($scope.users.length > 1) {
            $scope.users.splice(index, 1);
        }
        else if ($scope.users.length == 1) {
            $scope.users[0] = {};
        }
    };
```

Comment: Please provide snippet, so that we can help you better..

Comment: Can you post your code, or a pastebin/jsfiddle link pls

Answer (score 1):

Just update your code with the below one...
The problem is you have missed **type="button"** for your buttons.

```
   <div class="form-group " ng-repeat="(i, user) in users">
       <div class="col-sm-5" style="padding-right: 0px; margin-top: 0px">
           <div typeahead ng-model="users[i]">
           </div>

           <div class="col-sm-2 ng-scope" style="padding-left: 5px; margin-top: 0px">
           <button type="button" ng-click="removeUserInput(i)" class="btn pull-right m-t-n-xs remove-input">
              <i>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" style="color: white;"></span>
              </i>
            </button>

           <button type="button" ng-click="addUserInput()" class="btn pull-right m-t-n-xs add-input">
              <i>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" style="color: white;"></span>
              </i>
           </button>
         </div>
       </div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you are curious about why it has happened in that way,

> - Whenever you press `enter` inside `form`, the form submit action will be triggered along with the submit button onclick event.
> - A button without `type` attribute will behave like `submit` button.

In your code you didn't specify the `type` attribute for button so whenever you are pressing enter key

- It will try to execute the onclick event of submit button.
- Then it will try to execute form submit event

In your case since you didn't specify type attribute for button, buttons onclick event is executing that is reason your `$scope.RemoveItem(index_of_item)` function is executing itself even though you are not clicking the button.

#### DEMOs

**without `type` attribute**

Executes button onclick event along with form submit event

```html
<form onsubmit="javascript:alert('hi from form onsubmit')">
  <input type="text">
  <button onclick="javascript:alert('hi from button onclick')">click</button>
</form>
```

**With type attribute (fixed)**

```html
<form onsubmit="alert('hi from onsubmit')">
<input type="text">
<button type="button" onclick="alert('hi from button onclick')">click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining :)